# Comment-flag "No Longer Needed" misaligned in moderator timeline view

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, comment-flags, timeline

In the moderator timeline when you expand to see the comment flags, all content gets pushed to the first column instead of being displayed like all other entries:

[image]